# Can MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList() return delegates of other types?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following simplified implementation of Chain of Responsibility:

```
public class EventChainEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Handled { get; set; }
}

public static class EventChainExtensions
{
    public static void RaiseChain<T>(this EventHandler<T> handler, object sender, T args)
        where T : EventChainEventArgs
    {
        if (handler == null) return;
        var invocationChain = handler.GetInvocationList();
        foreach (var item in invocationChain)
        {
            ((EventHandler<T>)item)(sender, args);
            if (args.Handled)
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm unsure if it is correct to assume that `EventHandler<T>.GetInvocationList()` call returns only instances of `EventHandler<T>` or at least something that can be cast to that type?

Given [method group conversion variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx) I'd say that all delegate instances in the invocation list should be of the same type (otherwise that conversion won't be necessary), but it's kind of implicit assumption. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: As you can not combine delegates with different runtime type, `GetInvocationList` return delegate instances of same runtime type, as runtime type of delegate, you calling this method on.